# Vocal recording with DJM 600 + Traktor Audio 6 + Mic

Tags: recording

I'm a dj and I produce as well but have never recorded vocals in a decent quality for one of my tracks. Now, I got a singer coming to my home studio next month as she's enthusiastic about one of my pieces and wants to contribute with vocals. 
The question is: How do I record her voice? What I have at hand: A pioneer DJM 600 which I connect to my Mac Book Pro using a Traktor Audio 6 interface. I record Dj sets that way using Logic Pro X. The thing is, I do not yet own a mic. I would lean towards the Shure SM58 to begin with. What do you say? Would that work with the rest of my set up? Can I plug it in to the jacks on my interface? Can I use a cable that has XLR on the one side and Jacks on the other?

Any advice will be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options

The cheapest option is to get a $20 karaoke mic that ends in RCA.

You could also go for a USB-microphone if you only plan on using it in the studio. This essentially gets you a studio mic (which is much preferred over a SM58 or similar concert vocal microphone) at a reasonable price.

The best solution is upgrading your interface, AND getting a studio microphone. 
This doesn't have to cost too much, Focusrite has some studio-kits that aren't very expensive, and those get you set for anything you need to record.

I have never used or wanted to use my SM58's in the studio, ever. And I don't recommend that you do either.

If you need a mic for live performances the SM58 is a great choice. For the studio you'll want a large membrane mic.

Comment: A large-diaphragm mic provides a certain type of flattery to the voice.  A SM58, particularly with a hand cupped round the ball, provides a type of distortion typical of some urban styles!   Also, for several reasons, a vocalist may deliver a better performance with a hand-held 58 than with a fixed 'studio mic'.  Whatever you get, make plenty of practice recordings BEFORE the talent turns up!

Comment: Well, you asked in January, it's now September.  What gear did you use and how did the session go?  May we hear the result?